# how to set initial(default) value in dropdownButton?

Tags: dart, flutter

How to set initial value from cache to dropdown button?
have submitted button, if click submits button should add to drop-down button value. Now it's working. I need to add initial value to the drop-down button. and If add initial value and when click to submit button without selecting a value in dropdown selecting value should ant to pass

```
Container(
            child: ButtonTheme(
              alignedDropdown: true,
              child: DropdownButton<WorkSource>(
                isExpanded: true,
                value: _workSources,
                items: workSources.map((WorkSource value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<WorkSource>(
                    value: value,
                    child: Text(
                      value.description,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
                      workSourceIndex = value.id;
                      _workSources = value;
                    }),
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_workSources` in your code should be the initial value. Just assign value to that in `initState()`.

Comment: how to assign value? can to give example

Comment: i added like this in initState

Comment: ```getPriority().then((result) {
      setState(() {
        priority = result;
        _priorities.description = priority[0].description;
      });
    });```

Comment: i changed ```_priorities = priority[1];```..working well